# IOS app not working after deploying after the cable unplugged

Tags: ios

I'm new on IOS app development, I have build my IOS app and trying to deploy it to a real iPhone device for testing. Strangely, after unplugging the cable and relaunch the app and it's not working anymore and just freeze on the Splash screen. Can any advise what will be the issues?I have provided my logs file below. 
Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. By changing the "Edit Scheme" -> build configuration to "Release"